# Where is the rule for moving slowly when searching for traps that’s referenced by Dungeon Delver?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, traps

I'm having trouble finding the rule for one of the bulleted items for the Dungeon Delver feat:

> - You can search for traps while traveling at a normal pace, instead of only at a slow pace.

I can't find anything that talks about searching at a slow pace. In which book is this referenced?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Travel Pace

This is covered in the Basic Rules, Chapter 8 (Adventuring) under [Travel Pace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#TravelPace) (my emphasis):

> A fast pace makes characters less perceptive, while a **slow pace makes it possible to sneak around and to search an area more carefully** (see the “Activity While Traveling” section later in this chapter for more information).

Comment: BTW, the [2018 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) clarified the phrasing of the quoted bullet point of Dungeon Delver, changing the wording to: "Traveling at a fast pace doesn't impose the normal −5 penalty on your passive Wisdom (Perception) score."

Answer (score 9):

## Dungeon Delver negates the -5 to passive Perception

The [2018 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) changes the wording of the quoted benefit of the [Dungeon Delver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dungeon-delver) feat (PHB, p. 166) to clarify exactly what it refers to. It now reads:

> - Traveling at a fast pace doesn't impose the normal −5 penalty on your passive Wisdom (Perception) score.

As mentioned in [NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/153214/33569), this references the [Travel Pace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#TravelPace) rules; specifically, the table on PHB p. 182 specifies that traveling at a fast pace normally has the effect of:

> -5 penalty to passive Wisdom (Perception) scores

As of the 2018 PHB errata, it's clear that the last benefit of the Dungeon Delver feat negates this penalty.